# How correctly pass data to php using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-data

I am trying to send FormData to a PHP file. When pressing submit nothing happens, but when I send data separately it does work.

```html
<form method="post" class="code_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="my_file_id2" class='upload_img' type="file" name="my_file">
  <input id="code" class='code' type="text" name="my_text">
  <input type="submit" id='fertig-btn' class='prime_sty' name="submit">
</form>
```

```js
$(".code_form").on("submit", function(e) {
  var formData = new FormData();
  
  if ($(".upload_img").val() != '') {
    file = $(".upload_img").prop('files')[0];
    formData.append("my_file", file);
  }
  
  var dota = $(".code").val();
  
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "img_proc.php",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: {
      formData,
      dota,
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $(".user-success-code").html(data);
    }
  })

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Sending data like this works:

```
data: formData,
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure `dota` in `data:{ formData,dota,}` is correct, it looks like it would convert into a string, it might be expecting something like  `data:{ formData,'dota':dota,}` Same for formData

Comment: You need to just pass `data: formData`, don’t “mix” it with other parameters. Add your `dota` parameter _to_ the FormData object, same as you did with the file already. (Or just pass your form element to the FormData constructor, instead of adding individual entries.)

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen as Rory  McCrossan said if FormData is using all information has to be in that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending data using a FormData object all information has to be in that object. Therefore you need to `append()` the value from `.code` to it, as you do with the file information. Try this:

```js
$(".code_form").on("submit", function(e) {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('dota', $(".code").val());
  
  if ($(".upload_img").val() != '') {
    formData.append("my_file", $(".upload_img").prop('files')[0]);
  }  
  
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "img_proc.php",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
      $(".user-success-code").html(data);
    }
  })

  e.preventDefault();
});
```